# MeteorJS Iron Router - Is it possible to have the router controller in a separate JS file?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is there is a way to have the router controller in a different file, my router is getting pretty big and would like to spit the code up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just organize your code base as follow :

lib/router.js

```
Router.route("/",{
  name:"home",
  controller:"HomeController"
});

Router.route("/about",{
  name:"about",
  controller:"AboutController"
});
```

lib/controllers/home.js

```
HomeController=RouteController.extend({
  template:"home",
  onBeforeAction:function(){
    //
    this.next();
  },
  data:function(){
    return {
      //
    };
  }
});
```

lib/controllers/about.js

```
AboutController=RouteController.extend({
  template:"about",
  //
});
```

And so on...

Comment: This is not working for me I'm getting 
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Can you provide your code because I'm 100% sure this is a valid pattern.